# Struct containing Delegate of unknown type

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to have a struct for Commands. It will contain the name of the command, and a pointer to a function to execute when that command is called.

```
public struct Command {
        public string name;
        public delegate commandDelegate();
    }
```

This doesn't work because the delegate has no type. Some command's functions will be void and some will return a value. They will vary in number of arguments as well.

I was hoping to occupy my command list with something like this:

```
commands.Add(new Command { name = "exit", commandDelegate = new delegate void commandHelp(List<Command> commandList) });
```

This says type expected which I don't understand, since I'm giving it a void type, which matches the signature of the commandList method which is:

```
public static void commandHelp(List<Command> commandList) {
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (Command x in commandList) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}{1,-50}", x.name, "description");
            }
```

Clearly, I have no idea of how to go about this. If possible I'd like to do it this way because I'm only trying to learn some C# language features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Command` definition should be:

```
public struct Command {
    public string name;
    public Delegate commandDelegate;
}
```

then you can add `Command`s to your list with:

```
commands.Add(new Command { 
    name = "exit", 
    commandDelegate = new Action<List<Command>>(commandHelp) 
});
```

To execute the delegate, you can use `DynamicInvoke` with the arguments e.g.

```
commands[0].commandDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new List<Command> { });
```

Comment: How would I execute the function? I tried commands[0].commandDelegate(); but this says commandDelegate is a non-invocable member

Comment: It is saying that 'Command' does not contain a definition for 'DynamicInvoke' and no extension method 'DynamicInvoke' accepting a first argument of type 'Command' could be found. How do I specify the commandDelegate in the executing line

Comment: Works perfect. Would I use Func instead of Action if I wanted the command to return a value or take in more than one parameter? I couldn't upvote because of my reputation, but I marked as best answer